# Exception: AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, jersey-client

When trying a POST-Request using jersey 1.18, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;
at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.computeExceptionMessage(WebApplicationException.java:205)
at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.<init>(WebApplicationException.java:179)
at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.<init>(WebApplicationException.java:244)
at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:159)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.RequestWriter.writeRequestEntity(RequestWriter.java:300)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler._invoke(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:217)
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.voidHandle(WebResource.java:706)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$400(WebResource.java:74)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:555)
at jtmt.shell.commands.upld.TrcUploader.upload(TrcUploader.java:29)
at jtmt.shell.commands.trcrt.ICMPTraceRoute.run(ICMPTraceRoute.java:92)
at jtmt.shell.commands.Main.<init>(Main.java:42)
at jtmt.shell.commands.Main.main(Main.java:64)
```

The code that produces this is:

```
    Trace trc = Trace.fromTracerouteResult(trace);
    WebResource wr = _c.resource(URL);
    WebResource.Builder wrb = wr.cookie(new Cookie("user", USER));
    wrb = wrb.cookie(new Cookie("auth", AUTH));
    wrb.post(trc);
    return true;
```

The entiry `Trace` looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Trace {
    private Map<Integer,List<String>> addressesPerHop;
    private String source;
    private String traget;

    /* getters and setters */
}
```

I include the following jars when compiling and executing:

```
commons-cli-1.2.jar
jersey-server-1.18.jar
asm-3.1.jar
jersey-servlet-1.18.jar
jersey-client-1.18.jar
jersey-core-1.18.jar
```

Any Ideas whats missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Your version of Jersey is too old.  The method javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo() is part of the 2.0 JAX-RS spec.  See: https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#getStatusInfo().

Jersey 2.0 appears to be the first version that supports JAX-RS 2.0.

Comment: Thx. I feel dumb now.