# JAX-RS with Jersey & Grizzly: 500 Request failed for all requests

Tags: java, azure, jersey, jax-rs, grizzly

#### Hi

I need to develop simple web service on java.
I'm new to java tech and based on several articles decided to use JAX-RS (Jersey) with embedded http server (Grizzly2), because it looks suitable for building REST services and deployment seems to be trivial.

In my dev environment all works perfect (using IntllijIdea).

But when I try to deploy on test server every request returns "500 Internal Error" (even /application.wadl)

#### Here more info:

Simple resource

```
@Path("resource")
public class SpeechRecognition {
    @GET
    public Response test() {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.INFO, "resource test");
        return Response.ok("success", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

Simple resource config

```
public class SimpleApiServer extends ResourceConfig {
    public SimpleApiServer() {
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        register(LoggingFilter.class);
        register(JacksonFeature.class);

        property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");
        property(ServerProperties.TRACING_THRESHOLD, "VERBOSE");

        packages("com.mydomain");
    }
}
```

Simple app start

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://0.0.0.0:80", new SimpleApiServer());

    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", serverUri.toString()));
    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
}
```

Exception mapping

```
@Provider
public class AppExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Throwable> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Throwable ex) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.WARNING, "exception response");

        ex.printStackTrace();

        return Response.status(500).entity(Exceptions.getStackTraceAsString(ex)).type("text/plain")
            .build();
    }
}
```

#### What is happening

For every request I see in console

- that grizzly accepts it (prints all information about headers etc.)
 - and that resource code is executed ("resource test" is printed)


And nothing more.

In postman I receive "500 Request Failed" with no trace from Jersey in headers (though I specified property(ServerProperties.TRACING, "ALL");)

No information printed in server console about any exceptions.

I have an idea, that something bad happens when jersey tries to pass response to grizzly.

Does anyone has any thoughts about where should I look to troubleshoot this problem? I really stuck with it.

And I really don't want to rewrite everything (not this simple ill example, but lots more) to traditional java servlet-oriented code ('cause it's another piece of tech to learn about)

#### P.S.

Test server - is the docker container on azure linux VM. Requests are proxied by nginx to exposed docker port. Got web-site on Rails using the same scheme, which works fine.

When grizzly prints info about request it prints incorrect hostname. I.e. actual host name is **test.api.mydomain.com** and grizzly writes **GET http://test.api:80/resource**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok.
 
It was the Jersey version mismatch in dev and test environments.

[Remote debugging](http://hellotojavaworld.blogspot.ru/2010/11/remote-debugging-in-java.html) (with [IntellijIdea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/run-debug-configuration-remote.html)) showed, that in process of forming response

```
Exception: AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;
```

is thrown, wich led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616351/exception-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-response-getstatusinfoljavax) post. 
After fixing the dependencies all works fine.