# Discovery Client was unable to refresh its cache! status = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;

Tags: java, netflix-eureka

I am getting the below error, how ever my service is running fine.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Response.getStatusInfo()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/Response$StatusType;
    at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.computeExceptionMessage(WebApplicationException.java:205)
    at javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException.<init>(WebApplicationException.java:179)
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.readFrom(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:107)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:586)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:198)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77)
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.refreshRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1479)
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient$CacheRefreshThread.run(DiscoveryClient.java:1446)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

```
eureka:
  instance:
    port: 80
    nonSecurePortEnabled: true
    homePageUrl: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}/
    statusPageUrl: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}/actuator/info
    metadataMap:
      hostname: ${eureka.instance.hostname}
      port: 80
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 30
    leaseExpirationDurationInSeconds: 60
    preferIpAddress: false
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    preferSameZone: false
    serviceUrl:
    defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: my services are running fine,,,,but i get this error so many times in console,,,either i need the way to get rid of this log or to stop this error from happening,,i am good with any one of these.

Comment: Can u share your code here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616351/exception-abstractmethoderror-javax-ws-rs-core-response-getstatusinfoljavax Here you go

Comment: @UrvashiSoni i have pasted the YML configuration

Comment: @SMA i am not using jersey,,my services are running fine but this error keeps on happening ,,after 1 or 2 min

Comment: @ankit Please look at your stacktrace.   The `AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient` class is using jersey..